# How to get the values in dynamicaly append check box list

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I have created UI as the way what I want to enter data.

After selecting product name, flavors of that product append dynamically with check box.

All the check box data append dynamically using JS function. after that I tried to insert those data to database when button click. But I have problem in how to getting the ID of checkbox list which are checked.

Could any one please help me to figure out this problem?

I'm using `Codeigniter` framework for developing.

**JS:**

```
var ptype = $j("#cmb_freeproduct_type").val();        
    //alert(ptype);
    //$j('#eqtyrw').hide(500);
    $j.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'loadFlavorTypes',
    data: {ptype:ptype},
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
        var result = JSON.parse(data);
        //alert(result);
        var datas = [];

        for (var x = 0; x < result.length; x++) {


            datas.push('<tr id="'+result[x].product_flavour_id+'">'
                        +'<td>'
                        +'<input type="checkbox" name="fflavor_wise" id="fflavor_wise'+x+'" autocomplete="off" value=""></input>'
                        +'</td>'
                        +'<td id="fflavor'+x+'">      <b>'+result[x].product_flavour+'</b> </td>'

                    +'</tr>');

        }
        $j("#flavors_for_product_free").html(datas);
    },
            error: function(data){
        alert('error');
    }
       });
```

Comment: Please clarify your question by posting code that others might inspect.

Comment: Where is your code??

Answer (score 0):

jQuery:

```
// Find all checkboxes on the page that are currently checked.
var checked = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked");
```

Plain JavaScript:

```
// Find all input elements.
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
var checked = [];

// Cycle our input elements list and find the checkboxes 
// that are checked.
for ( var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++ ) {
    if ( inputs[i].type == "checkbox" && inputs[i].checked ) {
        checked.push(inputs[i]);
    }
}
```

In either case, you will now have an array containing checked checkboxes. Getting the ids of those should be pretty straight forward.

A strong argument for using jQuery when comparing these techniques.

Comment: i used this but it return [object,object]

Comment: Thnak you for your help. I insert data in every check box click event.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to give them all a `class` (e.g. `fflavor_wise_cb`), then you can easily get the checked ones:

```
var checkedCbs = $('.fflavor_wise_cb:checked');
```

Or since they all share the same `name`, you can use that:

```
var checkedCbs = $('input[type=checkbox][name="fflavor_wise"]:checked');
```

Then you can iterate through them using `each`:

```
checkedCbs.each(function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

In your code their value is empty, so to test better to give them a vale.

Answer (score 0):

First, Please put dataType:"JSON" in ajax code, then use jquery $(data)each(function(index)){}

I have made above mentioned changes in your code, please check.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'loadFlavorTypes',
    data: {ptype:ptype},
    dataType:"JSON",
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
        var result = data;

        //use jquery each function to iterate over the data 
        $(result).each(function(x){

            $("#flavors_for_product_free").append('<tr id="'+result[x].product_flavour_id+'">'
                        +'<td>'
                        +'<input type="checkbox" name="fflavor_wise" id="fflavor_wise'+x+'" autocomplete="off" value=""></input>'
                        +'</td>'
                        +'<td id="fflavor'+x+'">      <b>'+result[x].product_flavour+'</b> </td>'
                    +'</tr>');
        });
    },
            error: function(data){
        alert('error with'+data);
    }
       });
```